# powershell function + dictionary

Tags: function, powershell, dictionary

I don't understand this behavior:

```
function foo ($item, $dict_of_item) {
    if ($dict_of_item.keys -contains $item){
        return $dict_of_item[$item] }
    else{
        return $item }       
}

$dict = @{
'a' = 1
'b' = 2
'c' = 3}

foo('a',$dict)
a

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
c                              3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
b                              2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
a                              1
```

I want return code of char and I don't understand why I get dictionary in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function incorrectly.  You don't place parenthesis around arguments, but pass them like command-line arguments.  So in your case, change:

```
foo('a',$dict)
```

to:

```
foo 'a' $dict
```

or, more clearly:

```
foo -item 'a' -dict_of_item $dict
```

PowerShell was interpreting `('a',$dict)` as an array and so you had:

```
$item = ('a',$dict)
$dict_of_item = $null
```

Since your test fails with these arguments, it is returning `$item` to you.  That is, it is returning an array with a character and a dictionary, which is what you see on screen.